# Perfect forwarding trickery

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

If your object has multiple parameters and can take l or r value references the number of constructors jumps quickly. Can a little template trickery simplify the situation or does this cause issues that I am not aware of OR am I over-thinking it and there is standard way of simplifying this?

```
// In the following context I using std::string as an example o
// something that can be moved or copied, where we would prefer
// a move rather than a copy.

// With just two parameters.
// I need 4 constructors to do the correct thing (copy/move) correctly.
class Original
{
    std::string   val1;
    std::string   val2;
    public:
        Original(std::string const& v1, std::string const& v2): val1(v1), val2(v2) {}
        Original(std::string const& v1, std::string&&      v2): val1(v1), val2(std::move(v2)) {}            
        Original(std::string&&      v1, std::string const& v2): val1(std::move(v1)), val2(v2) {}            
        Original(std::string&&      v1, std::string&&      v2): val1(std::move(v1)), val2(std::move(v2)) {}
};
```

If the parameter types were templates I could use perfect forwarding.

```
// This is a check to see if a template is the specific class.
// Or can be trivially constructed from the parameters.
template<typename Actual>
using ValidString = std::enable_if_t<std::is_trivially_constructible_v<std::string, Actual>, bool>;


// With these I can simplify my requirement of 4 constructors
// and simplify to a single templaed constructor that can do perfect forwarding.
class Alternative
{
    std::string   val1;
    std::string   val2;
    public:
        template<typename V1, typename V2, ValidString<V1> = true, ValidString<V2> = true>
        Original(V1 v1, V2 v2): val1(std::forward<V1>(v1)), val2(std::forward<V2>(v2)) {}
};
```

Two questions:

1. Is there already a technique to allow perfect forwarding of parameters that I missed?
2. If there is not a current technique, what are the issues here?

Comment: You may like [this](https://youtu.be/6lurOCdaj0Y) video by Herb Sutter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this in your specific case would be to do:

```
class Original
{
    std::string val1;
    std::string val2;
public:
    Original(std::string v1, std::string v2) noexcept
      : val1{ std::move(v1) }
      , val2{ std::move(v2) }
    {}
};
```

This is often good enough for constructors. It potentially does copy+move instead of just a copy, but most types are cheap to move anyway. One case where you may have to do your version is when the assignment is conditional. Something like:

```
template<typename T, typename Y>
void foo(T&& t, Y&& y)
{
   if (condition)
   {
      varT = std::forward<T>(t);
      varY = std::forward<Y>(y);
   }
}
```

You can't get away with copy+move, because you definitely don't want an unnecessary copy.

Comment: You are forcing a copy in the parameter. So you are always ending up with the worst case!

Comment: @MartinYork No, that's not correct. r-values are moved. Only l-values are copied, which is what your version does as well.

Comment: Ahh. Something so obvious and simple when you think about it.

Comment: So L-Valeu => Copy and Move. And R-Value => Move and Move.

Comment: @MartinYork exactly. It also helps with exception-safety, and the function can now be `noexcept`.

Answer (score 0):

"If your object has multiple parameters"

I think, it depends a bit on the context and the amount of parameters. I'm often faced with common parametrization situations, where the introduction of a simple parameters container with simple direct (braced) initialization seemed to be a fitting solution, in terms of design and performance. If you want full flexible paramater amounts for the construction further on ( [0..N] ), the named parameter idiom here (in combination) might be a powerful additional approach. But as I said, it depends on the context and the maximum amount of possible parameters, wouldn't apply this for two parameters solely for the most cases. Then, Ayxan Haqverdili's answer is the recommended one by Herb Sutter for instance, the most flexible, clean and non-intrusive approach available so far I think.